# I wish to know how do we set session with function instead of assigning values

Tags: jquery, function, random, session-storage

How do I fix these random values so that it remains the same till 12 hours. This is getting changed each time the page is refreshed.

This is my code assigning random numbers to a section

```js
function getRandomNumber(minNumber, maxNumber) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) +
    minNumber);
}

getRandomNumber();

$('.someclass').each(function() {
  var x = $(this);
  const y = $(.sproof); //sproof is the snippet where the value 
  is being inserted //
  y.insertAfter(x.find('.someclass2'));
});

$('.someclass3').each(function() {
  var minNumber = 700;
  var maxNumber = 701;
  $(this).html(getRandomNumber(minNumber, maxNumber));
});

$('.someclass3').each(function() {
  var minNumber = 700;
  var maxNumber = 701;
  $(this).html(getRandomNumber(minNumber, maxNumber));
});
```

The random number needs to be the same throughout the day even after refresh. My case is that the numbers are generated each time the page is refreshed.

Comment: Do they need to stay the same on one machine or on all machines visiting the website?

Comment: Thanks for response. It's for all the machine for that day!

Comment: In this case you first need to look at your back-end. You back-end/server should determine these numbers and then share them with your front-end/website. What back-end are you using (e.g. PHP, NodeJS, ASP.NET etc.)?